# Flash Builder 4 + Red5 IDE Plugin

Tags: eclipse, flash, eclipse-plugin, flash-builder, red5

Anybody know how to install Red5 IDE Plugin for Adobe Flash Builder 4?
Adobe Flash builder 4 comes with an integrated installation of Eclipse, but If I follow the instructions on Red5 site I get:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: Red5 Feature 0.2.0 (org.red5.feature.feature.group 0.2.0)
Missing requirement: Red5 Feature 0.2.0 (org.red5.feature.feature.group 0.2.0) requires 'org.eclipse.jst.server.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found
```

I have tried everywhere but can't find any help.

Thanks in advance.

**Answer**
Flash Bulder 4 has Eclipse Galileo as integrated IDE, in order to make Red5 Plugin work first you have to install Eclipse Web Tools Platform (http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo/) and then you can install Red5 IDE Plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the flash builder is not built on top of a full blown eclipse (it does not make sense to do so.), So you need to install the server components, if you are envisioning running servers from eclipse. The easiest way to do this is to install the all-in-one package from eclipse and then install the Flash builder plugin or you could try installing [WTP](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/) (Web Tool Platform) tools in your existing flash builder.

Answer (score 1):

Flashbuilder is available in two flavours. Standalone or as a eclipse plugin. I am currently doing all my flashbuilder plugin's(Currently working on a PureMVC plugin and need beta testers) development using eclipse indigo and flashbuilder 4.0(the plugin version) without any problem.

Short answer is :)
Just install the eclipse environment you want and then install the flashbuilder plugin..
Should work like a charm.

Geirr