# Installing RED5 plugin to Flash Builder

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, red5

I have Eclipse Builder 4.6 and would like to put in the Red5 Plugin.

I had difficulties so I read the information here in SO at the following link:

[Flash Builder 4 + Red5 IDE Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7275616/flash-builder-4-red5-ide-plugin)

Unfortunately, the solution presented there doesn't work for a variety of reasons:

1. The update site provided in the solution is for Galileo. Flash Builder 4.6 is based on Indigo
2. Even if the site was correct, the repo there has business tools, AJAX tools, and Web Service tools. It does not have WTP. Furthermore, you can't install anything from there because there are unspecified dependencies preventing installation.
3. Even when I found WTP for Indigo (http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/indigo), Builder cannot install it because of several unspecified dependencies that are apparently among the many components that are not shipped with Builder(!).

So: has anyone out there managed to install Red5 plugin into Flash Builder??? If so, what did you have to do in order to do it?

Thanks in advance for any help on this somewhat critical matter.